# Compile error on TeamCity using Microsoft Build Tools 2015, but not in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0, teamcity-9.0

Following instructions to upgrade my solution to support the new C# language features, I changed my TeamCity build step's `MsBuild Version` option from `Microsoft .NET 4.5` to `Microsoft Build Tools 2015`. I can build the solution fine in Visual Studio 2015, but my Teamcity build fails as follows:

> Class.cs(323, 72): error CS0407: 'void Class.Foo()' has the wrong return type

Line 323 of Class.cs looks like this:

```
    LogHelper.WithErrorLogging(this.log, "Foo", false, this.Foo, true);
```

Class.Foo() has the following signature:

```
    private void Foo()
```

LogHelper.WithErrorLogging() has several overloads, but the one I want to call is:

```
    public static void WithErrorLogging(ILogger log, string name, bool shouldThrow, Action action, bool logOnlyOnError = false)
```

As I say, the build succeeds locally in Visual Studio 2015, failing on TeamCity, but if I remove this overload of LogHelper.WithErrorLogging() then the TeamCity build works again:

```
    public static T WithErrorLogging<T>(ILogger log, string name, bool shouldThrow, Func<T> action, T errorValue = default(T), bool logOnlyOnError = false)
```

My conclusion is that the Microsoft Build Tools 2015 compiler is incorrectly resolving the overload to call, by taking the final `true` parameter as the `errorValue` parameter of the second overload, thus inferring the generic type argument `T` is `bool` and finally failing to compile because `this.Foo()` is an `Action` and not a `Func<T>`, but without ever considering the first overload as a possible valid method to call.

Can anyone shed any light on why this should be? Is this a compiler bug, or is there a valid reason why this code ought not to compile as C#6?

Comment: Completely unrelated, I would recommend to use `nameof(Foo)` instead of the hardcoded string `"Foo"` in your code. This makes the code more flexible for refactoring.

Comment: Thanks Mafii - I think that's is a C#6 feature so I certainly will do once I've got this issue sorted :)